# customizing the nutch indexwriter to map values into elastic docin multielvel(like JSON)

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch, indexwriter

I am going to develop a plugin for apache nutch to customise the indexwriter, my problem is that in the plugin when you have access to NutchDocument , you just put data at the first level not at the second level. for instance for "a", "location" and "url" easily you can put data by `doc.add("url", "www.csad.com");` while for "company" which is a complex object it is impossible to send an object of company calss.

this is my idnex_Metadata in elastic search

```
{
   "properties":{
      "a":{
         "type":"string"
      },
      "company":{
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{
            "id":{
               "type":"integer",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "type":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            },
            "name":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "location":{
               "type":"geo_point"
            },
            "slug":{
               "type":"string",
               "index":"not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      },
      "location":{
         "type":"geo_point",
         "lat_lon":"true"
      },
      "url":{
         "type":"string",
         "index":"not_analyzed"
      }
   }
}
```

I can't send data to "company" in java plugin, while without company it works well

```
      doc.add("location", rs.getString("ic_company_lat") + "," + rs.getString("ic_company_lng"));

      Company cmp = new Company();
      cmp.setId(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ic_company_id")));
      cmp.setType("type");
      cmp.setName(rs.getString("ic_company_name"));
      doc.add("company", cmp);
```

Comment: You need to provide a little more info about this what is the specific error that you're getting is in the Nutch side? is an ES error? are you getting an error at all? or just an empty string?

Comment: my point is related to the plugin that I am developing for nutch, which indexes the data into ES at this moment I am attaching new fields I don't have a problem when the field is at the first level of _source but when it ios going to deal with the deeper level it doesn't do anything

Comment: regarding location which is of the type of geo_point  I need to have a list of locations but can't attach from the plugin

Comment: But what do you mean with "it doesn't do anything" part you didn't got any error message from Nutch? or is just that the field (company) is empty on ES?

Comment: I think that @JavadMalekshahkoohi is trying to save a complex object to elasticsearch using a nutch custom plugin, but he cannot, there is any way to do that?

Comment: Yep I understood that, but what is the actual error or wrong behaviour?, if Nutch is trowing an error when setting the `company` field, then could be something related to how this is handled in `NutchDocument`/`NutchField`, but could also be that the `IndexWriter` implementation for ES doesn't handle the object the right way, any how more info is needed to pinpoint the problem and find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using the `elastic-indexer` plugin, Nutch out of the box doesn't support using custom classes for indexing (you can add it to the `NutchDocument` instance, but you'll need to write your own logic to handle it in the indexers ES/Solr, i.e modifying the plugins).

You can accomplish what you want using a simple `HashMap`:

```
Map map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("name", "Company Name");
...

doc.add("company", map);
```

With this you'll get a document with the structure that you're after in ES:

```
"company": {
    "name": "Awesome company",
    ...
},
```